# After Move http to https of wordpress thrid party API's not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, amazon-cognito, custom-theme

I have implemented the  sigle signon  in worpress with Java with Aws cognito.

it is working fine with http but after moving http to https. API's are not working and throwing the error below:

```
WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [http_request_failed] => Array
                (
                    [0] => cURL error 35: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
                )

        )

    [error_data] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I have consumed the  get and Post API like below:

```
$bodyData = array(
      'username' => $_POST['username'],
      'password' => $_POST['password']
      );
   $response = wp_remote_post('https://example.com:8083/digitalIdentityProvider/login', 
               array(
                  'method' => 'POST',
                  'timeout' => 45,
                  'redirection' => 5,
                  'httpversion' => '2.0',
                  'sslverify'   => true,
                  'blocking' => true,
                  'headers' => array('Content-Type'=> 'application/json'),
                  'body' => json_encode($bodyData) ,
                  'cookies' => array()
                  ));
```

Could you please someone guide or suggest ?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a self signed certificate? Change sslverify to false and try again

Comment: tried but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with wordpress code and AWS, I found the issue with Aws ELB and Load Balancer .

SSL Certificate has applied to LB and Third party API and wordpress were hosted on AWS EC2 and for EC2 there was not SSL certificate and I was trying to access API with
HTTPS:

`https://example.com:8083/digitalIdentityProvider/login` hence request was not verifying over there hence  I was not receiving any response from API.

I have changed API call

from `https://example.com:8083/digitalIdentityProvider/login`

to `http://example.com:8083/digitalIdentityProvider/login`

after change it https to http. it working fine.